# API for Google Docs Viewer

Tags: google-docs-api

Please refer the below [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-documents-list-api/HOvorImoAM8) from [Google Documents List API Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-documents-list-api/HOvorImoAM8) and someone please suggest me a solution.

```
    Hi again Jags,

    Sorry, I missed one thing, you might be able to use the embed link, i.e. that link with rel http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#embed. That will give you a link to embed the resource.

    Regards


    On Tue, Mar 27, 2012 at 10:59 AM, Ali Afshar wrote:
    Hi Jags,

    Sorry, there is no real API there as such to do what you want to achieve. You should probably export it as a format that you can embed in your page.

    Regards


    On Sat, Mar 17, 2012 at 3:18 AM, Jags wrote:
    Hi,

    Can someone help me in figuring out if there is an API available to use Google Docs Viewer where I want to upload a document and it should give me a Google Docs View Url for the document so that I can embed it in our website. Currently in Docs Viewer, the only option I find is viewing a publicly available document by passing the url for it as a param as in http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=xxxxxxxxxx. Is this the only way that I can view in Google Docs. Please someone assist if I missing something.
  If this isn't possible by Docs Viewer is it supported in Google Docs where I'll upload it to user's google account and thereafter even the author of the document should have just a VIEW only option for the document.

    TIA,
    Jagadeesh
```

Now can someone please provide me a Java sample code to set the 'xmlns' as 'http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#embed' to the document entry. I am getting an InvalidEntryException.
        `com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Invalid request URI
GDatainvalidRequestUriInvalid request URI`
So please suggest me a possible solution to resolve this.

Comment: For the benefit of other users, would you please edit your question  and provide the full question/context here?

Comment: @VicFryzel Any inputs on this?

Answer (score 1):

+1 to this one

> Blockquote
>   Now can someone please provide me a Java sample code to set the 'xmlns' as 'http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#embed' to the document entry. I am getting an InvalidEntryException. com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Invalid request URI GDatainvalidRequestUriInvalid request URI So please suggest me a possible solution to resolve this.

After reading this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-documents-list-api/HOvorImoAM8), even I'm looking for a java example ob how to set the 'xmlns' as 'http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#embed' to the document entry.